# Rename the Endnotes section in ToC

Tags: enotez

I have a little problem, I want a pages with my resources from internet sites (different from the references). So I used the enotez package.

When I print with

```
\printendnotes
```

The title of the section is "Notes" And I would like something else. I already try in the pre-document

```
\renewcommand{\endnotessname}{blablabla}
```

but it doesnt work.

Thank's for your answers!

Comment: @JohnKormylo the package `enotez` does not know of `\notesname`.

Comment: The `enotez` manual mentions the `list-name` option ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have two options.

1. Use the option `list-name`:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}

   \usepackage{enotez}
   \setenotez{
     list-name = My wonderful title
   }

   \begin{document}

   Test\endnote{example}

   \printendnotes

   \end{document}
   ```
2. Change the translation of the keyword `enotez-title` (you might want use your `babel` language here instead of English):

   ```
   \documentclass{article}

   \usepackage{enotez}
   \DeclareTranslation{english}{enotez-title}{My wonderful title}

   \begin{document}

   Test\endnote{example}

   \printendnotes

   \end{document}
   ```

Both my examples give

[image]